# XML to CSV using XSLT linefeed and spaces at start of first value

Tags: xml, csv, xslt

When I place the XSLT and XML into online XSLT validators I appear to get spaces and linefeeds at the start (0A20) of the output, i am using Onlinetoolz to test http://www.online-toolz.com/tools/xslt-transformation.php but other engines give the same result, why am I getting and how do I remove the characters at the start?

Output below showing it with spaces at start I would expect and want no linefeeds or spaces at the start

```
     DESKTOP-H3B7ONO,20171016T100436Z,3A80-071084
```

XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<document>
  <properties>
    <basic>
      <property id="hostName">
        <value>DESKTOP-H3B7ONO</value>
      </property>
      <property id="generationDate">
        <value>20171016T100436Z</value>
      </property>
      <property id="machineId">
        <value>3A80-071084</value>
      </property>
    </basic>
  </properties>
</document>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="Utf-8" />
<xsl:template match="basic">
<xsl:value-of select="property[@id='hostName']/value"/>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="property[@id='generationDate']/value"/>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="property[@id='machineId']/value"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an explicit empty template for whitespace-only `text()` nodes to ensure that the built-in templates don't emit the whitespace in your output.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="Utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()[not(normalize-space())]"/>

    <xsl:template match="basic">
        <xsl:value-of select="property[@id = 'hostName']/value"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="property[@id = 'generationDate']/value"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="property[@id = 'machineId']/value"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or add a template match on the root node, and then only apply-templates for the `basic` element, skipping default processing of the other content in the document that would emit the whitespace `text()`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="Utf-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document/properties/basic"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="basic">
        <xsl:value-of select="property[@id = 'hostName']/value"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="property[@id = 'generationDate']/value"/>
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="property[@id = 'machineId']/value"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the indentation from your source XML is being passed through by the XSLT parser. To get rid of it, add `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` before the template declaration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="Utf-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="basic">
<xsl:value-of select="property[@id='hostName']/value"/>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="property[@id='generationDate']/value"/>
<xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="property[@id='machineId']/value"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```